# How can I determine rotation direction when rewinding armature coils

Tags: universal-motor

I want to rewind a burnt armature coils of universal motor. Which segment of commutator with respect to the armature slot should I begin with in order to make it rotate clockwise? I will apreciate if I get a detailed answer in rewinding.
Note that, I don’t want to reverse connection of brush terminals, also I am good at this task of rewinding but the only issue is to determine rotation direction after rewinding.

Comment: You need to make good notes on how the original windings were done. There’s no universal rule that says all motors are wound the same.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is a series universal motor, if you have it running backwards simply reverse the leads to the two brushes or the field windings, that will cause it to reverse. The relationship between the two determines rotation. There are some that the brush alignment is critical and this would reduce its life. Kartman's is good on all projects as are lots of pictures. It may be possible to get that information from the manufacturer, just a guess, I am not sure.

Comment: Reversing the leads causes too hot and sparks... thats why I need to rewind so that it changes direction. The only thing I think I need right now is how to start rewinding and which direction.

Comment: Is it possible to rotate the brush ring, that would be much easier if possible.

Comment: Not possible... I am sad 

Comment: Me to, you have a tough job ahead of you. Good Luck1